# How to convert multiple date format strings into datetime in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to move data from one temporary table into  main table in sql
The Temporary table have date values in nvarchar data type with below formats

1. "dd/mm/yyyy" - 27/04/2020 and 27/4/2020
2. "mm/dd/yyyy" - 04/27/2020
3. "dd-mm-yy"   - 27-4-20
4. "dd-mm-yyyy" - 27.04.2020 and 27.4.2020

anyone can you please help me to convert the nvarchar values into datetime
Thanks in Advance

Comment: What DBMS are you using? From the syntax I suspect MS SQL Server, but please verify it in your question and in the tags.

Comment: I am using ms Sql server 2014

Comment: Step 0: strongly berate whoever came up with that input format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with the following expression:

```
DATEFROMPARTS(SUBSTRING(@DateString,3,4),RIGHT(@DateString,2),LEFT(@DateString,2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `cast` - but you'll have to break the string and reconstruct it again, to `yyyyMMdd` - which is one of the two string representation date formats specified in ISO8601 - and therefor not culture-specific:

```
DECLARE @DateString NVarchar(max)='24202006';
SELECT CAST(RIGHT(@DateString, 6) + LEFT(@DateString,2) As Date);
```

Result:

```
2020-06-24
```